# Breeze custom validation

Tags: validation, breeze

How do i pass entity reference to Validation Context in breeze when doing conditional validation?

Consider the following scenario:

I have radio button list which is not directly bound to breeze entity but is bound to my view model property. Depending on radio button selection, i want to validate other inputs on the form that are bound to my breeze data entity.

I tried building custom validation on the radio button where my validation function holds reference to the radio button selection in built-in value property of validation context. Now, i am trying to access my entity object in the validation function to evaluate other input of my forms based on radio button selection.

Comment: Don't follow the question. Can you show us a tiny sample of code and html. Also are you using Angular or Knockout

Comment: I meant to do entity level validation. I wanted to pass entity to my validation factory and then perform conditional validation by inspecting other properties on my entity. I found documentation on breezejs site on how to do one. [http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an arbitrary example of max length validation. Use the context to access the entity and add the logic you need after that.

```
        function maxLengthValidatorFn(value, context) {
           var someValue = context.entity.SomeProperty;
           //Do something with some value.
           if (value && value.length > context.maxLength)
          return false;
           return true;
        }

        function maxLengthValidatorFactory(context) {
            return new breeze.Validator(
                "maxLength",
                maxLengthValidatorFn,
                { messageTemplate: "'%hrn%' exceeds maximum character length of %maxLength%", hrn: context.propertyLabel, maxLength: context.maxLength }
            );
        }
```

Comment: context.entity property doesnt seem to be in the breeze documentation